# Why VideoView doesn't play file from path

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using VideoView on Activity and I record video ( I checked it is on "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/v110.3gp" exists) and when I try in code

```
videoView.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/v110.3gp");
videoView.start();
```

nothing happens. That file exists but videoView doesn't want to play that. What can be wrong ?

Comment: Have you set the permissions?

Comment: @Andro Yes, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

You can't be 100% sure that all phones use /mnt/sdcard as the external storage directory. Use

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

```
videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+/"DCIM/v110.3gp");
```

Comment: I captured imaged and get that path from Uri ( from getData ) and I save that path and try to reload later but it doesn't work.